# How to find a pair of number in SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a problem with regular expression in Oracle. I need to find a pair of number which is the same for example:

```
1111
1212
1313
1414 
2020
3030
```

and I have a problem with how to find only this pair and use Regular expression or maybe like a statement?

```
REGEXP_LIKE(Vvalue,'[1-9][1-9][1-9][1-9]$');
```

but when I try this option I get 1111 but the next is 1112.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex needs a "back reference" to make sure that the first group of (two) digits is the same as the second:

```
where regexp_like(value, '^([0-9]{2})\1$')
```

If you want to disallow leading zeros:

```
where regexp_like(value, '^([1-9][0-9])\1$')
```

The regex means: the first two digits followed by exactly the same two digits. `(..)` creates a group and `\1` references that group.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number to start with, the simplest option is probably to uses artihmetics:

```
where floor(mynum / 100) = mod(mynum, 100)
```